# How to deploy SSL certificates on Flask-based web app?

Tags: docker, flask, ssl, certbot

I would like to deploy SSL certificate on my website to support https protocol.

Using Certbot 2.8.0, I successfully get the certificate:

```
~$ sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d www.toxiverse.com -d toxiverse.com
```

It returns:

> Successfully received certificate.

> Certificate is saved at: /etc/letsencrypt/live/toxiverse.com/fullchain.pem
>
> Key is saved at:         /etc/letsencrypt/live/toxiverse.com/privkey.pem
>
> This certificate expires on 2024-04-16.
>
> These files will be updated when the certificate renews.
>
> Certbot has set up a scheduled task to automatically renew this certificate in the background.

Then I copy the certificates to folder /root/ssl for convenience:

```
$ sudo -s scp /etc/letsencrypt/live/toxiverse.com/privkey.pem /root/ssl
```

```
$ sudo -s scp /etc/letsencrypt/live/toxiverse.com/fullchain.pem /root/ssl
```

```
$ sudo -s scp /etc/letsencrypt/live/toxiverse.com/cert.pem /root/ssl
```

```
$ sudo -s scp /etc/letsencrypt/live/toxiverse.com/chain.pem /root/ssl
```

And then I changed dockerfile to:

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN useradd toxpro

WORKDIR /home/toxpro

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m venv venv
RUN venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt

# netcat is a program
# necessary for troubleshooting
# the networking
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat-traditional


COPY app app
COPY ssl ssl
RUN pip install pyopenssl
RUN mkdir logs
RUN mkdir data
RUN mkdir instance # this is necessary for digital ocean

COPY boot.sh ./
RUN chmod +x boot.sh

COPY boot_worker.sh ./
RUN chmod +x boot_worker.sh

COPY boot_dashboard.sh ./
RUN chmod +x boot_dashboard.sh

RUN apt-get install libxrender1
ENV FLASK_APP app.py

RUN chown -R toxpro:toxpro ./
USER toxpro

EXPOSE 5000
```

As well as docker-compose-do.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    redis:
        image: redis
        volumes:
            - ./redis:/usr/local/etc/redis

    toxpro:
        build: .
        env_file:
            - docker-environment-do.env
        ports:
            - "443:5000"
        image: toxpro:lastest
        volumes:
            - ./instance/:/home/toxpro/instance
            - ./data/:/home/toxpro/data
            - ./root/ssl/fullchain.pem:/home/toxpro/fullchain.pem
            - ./root/ssl/privkey.pem:/home/toxpro/privkey.pem
        entrypoint: ["./boot.sh"]
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true

    worker:
        build: .
        env_file:
            - docker-environment-do.env
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - toxpro
        entrypoint: ["./boot_worker.sh"]
        volumes:
            - ./instance/:/home/toxpro/instance
            - ./data/:/home/toxpro/data
            - ./root/ssl/fullchain.pem:/home/toxpro/fullchain.pem
            - ./root/ssl/privkey.pem:/home/toxpro/privkey.pem
volumes:
  instance_vol:
```

boot.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
source venv/bin/activate
exec gunicorn -b :5000 --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm --certfile ssl/cert.pem --keyfile ssl/privkey.pem --workers=2 --timeout 90  --access-logfile - --error-logfile - "app:create_app()"
```

boot_worker.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
source venv/bin/activate
exec rq worker toxpro-tasks --name toxpro-tasks --url redis://toxpro-redis-1:6379
```

#!/bin/bash
And then copy local to server:

```
scp -r ./* toxpro@192.241.131.84:/home/toxpro
```

Then compose the containers on server:

```
sudo docker compose -f docker-compose-do.yml up -d --build --force-recreate
```

the three containers successfully started. However, when I try to connect to the website by SSL, it showed "wrong version number":

> wget https://toxiverse.com
>
> --2024-01-17 23:14:16--  https://toxiverse.com/
>
> Resolving toxiverse.com (toxiverse.com)... 192.241.131.84
>
> Connecting to toxiverse.com (toxiverse.com)|192.241.131.84|:443... connected.
>
> OpenSSL: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
>
> Unable to establish SSL connection.

The website doesn't work as well when I try to open it. Is there any mistake I made in the process deploying SSL certificates?

I tried re-apply for the certificates but it doesn't work.

Comment: How are you running Flask? What are the contents of `boot.sh`and `boot_worker.sh`? It also seems to me that you don't know much about what you are doing. Are you following some sort of tutorial or guide to deploy this?

Comment: Edited and added the supplementary files. I am following a tutorial from another people whose app is also flask-based

Comment: Reading about the error: `The typical reasons for this are wrong proxy configuration, captive portals or similar in the network or firewalls blocking connections. ` In your server do you have any proxy running to serve your website? Like nginx or apache? Or do you just expose port 443 directlt

Comment: No. I am just using gunicorn